# VMware.VumAutomation module is not currently supported on the Core edition of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vmware

I'm developing a PowerShell script to run from linux and inspect VMware ESXi host and perform critical patching.

The script I've got:

```html
pwsh <<'EOF'
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
Import-Module VMware.VumAutomation

Connect-VIServer {vmwareVcenterServer.ip} `
    -User "{vmwareVcenterUser.user}" `
    -Password "{vmwareVcenterUser.password}"

Scan-inventory -entity {vmwareVcenterServer.ip}

write-host "Placing host in Maintenance Mode"
Get-VMHost -Name {vmwareVcenterServer.ip} | set-vmhost -State Maintenance

write-host "Deploying VMware Host Critical & Non Critical Patches"
get-baseline -name *critical* | remediate-inventory -entity {vmwareVcenterServer.ip} -confirm:$false

write-host "Removing host from Maintenance Mode"
Get-VMHost -Name {vmwareVcenterServer.ip} | set-vmhost -State Connected

EOF
```

Before importing Vum.Automation module, the Scan-Inventory and Get-Baseline commands return errors:

```html
Scan-inventory : The 'Scan-inventory' command was found in the module 'VMware.VumAutomation', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module VMware.VumAutomation'.
```

If I import the Vum.Automation module the following error is returned:

```html
VMware.VumAutomation module is not currently supported on the Core edition of PowerShell.
```

Is there a work around for this issue?

Comment: What version of PowerCLI do you have installed? You can use the get-module command to see the version number.

Comment: I had PowerCLI version 11. I've updated to version 12 and `VMware.Vum.Automation` successfully imports.

Comment: Awesome! You should also be able to use "#!/usr/bin/env pwsh" at the top of the PowerCLI script to run it the same way you would bash - just make sure to import the module(s) you need in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VMware.PowerCLI` module was version 11. I've upgraded to version 12 and `VMware.Vum.Automation` successfully imports.

```
Update-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -RequiredVersion 12.7.0.20091289 -Force | `
tee -a /tmp/attune_log.tmp
```